# Pass List as Sql Table Type Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2012, generic-list

I'm trying to pass the list of my class as `DbParameter`. Probably the **table type** is defined in my stored procedure.

Now, I'm not getting how to pass the `List<>` into the stored procedure as there is table type defined which accepts `Tables` only.

Here, I'm putting my method.

```
public static AddCustomer(List<Customer> customer)
{
      List<DbParameter> lstDbParameters = null;

      try
      {
        #region Set the Parameters
        lstDbParameters = new List<DbParameter>();
        SqlParameter dbAcceptedBillDetails = new SqlParameter("@Customers",
                                                             customer);

        dbAcceptedBillDetails.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        lstDbParameters.Add(dbAcceptedBillDetails as DbParameter);
        lstDbParameters.Add(CDDAC.MakeDbParameter(dbProvider,
                                                  "@ErrorMessage",
                                                  DbType.String,
                                                  null,
                                                  500,
                                                  ParameterDirection.Output));
        #endregion

        //Call the static ExecuteNonQuery method.
        CDDAC.ExecuteNonQuery(dbProvider,
                              connectionString,
                              "AddCustomer",
                              CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                              lstDbParameters.ToArray());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
```

And I'm getting error like this:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1.

I know i can convert this list into `DataTable` and then pass it in the stored procedure but it seems time consuming.  :(

Comment: Post the code for `CDDAC.MakeDbParameter` and the stack trace of the error.

Comment: If you look at the [TechNet documentation on how to call a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), you see that you have three choices: `DataTable`, `IDataReader` or a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` - you need to provide *one of those three options* - take your pick

Comment: @Keith, CDDAC.MakeDBParameter is common utility for our projects. its just simlply make the parameter for SP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, i got my answer byself. But during finding, i got that there is no way exist to convert `List<>` to `IEnumerable<>` directly.

But this article is very useful to transact data through `object` or `List<Obj>`

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pchandraker/passing-table-valued-parameter-to-stored-procedu-part-2/

very useful. :)

Comment: Came here because I'm having the same problem. Yeah, .asenumerable() doesn't do it, that was one of my early guesses.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question a bit old, but I found another way to pass a list to table type parameter by converting list into datatable. So your code can be like this :

```
public static AddCustomer(DataTable customer)
{
      try
      {
        DbCommand dbcomm = CDDAC.GetStoredProcCommand("name your stored procedure");
        CDDAC.AdInParameter(dbcomm, "@Param", SqlDbType.Structured, customer); //@param is an input parameter from your storedprocedure
        CDDAC.ExecuteNonQuery(dbcomm);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
```

Just make sure you have created type for data customer in your database.

Comment: Please read the problem carefully first then provide your suggestion/solution